# How can I store a string in textfile1 into a variable in textfile2?

Tags: linux, string, bash, macos, scripting

Let's say we have two files text1.txt and text2.txt

text 1 stores data and reads something like this:

```
line1: "peter.petterson@xyz.com passwordtext"
line2: "anne.anneson@xyz.com passwordtext"
```

*the "line1:" and "" are not contained in the file. I only put them in here to make clear I have two lines that look similar.*

Now what I want to do is to create the variables "name" "surname", "password" and "email" in textfile2.

Comment: Use `read` in bash. `awk` is great for this as well. Split on ws and assign to a variable. Post some code and we'd gladly assist you if you're stuck. Good luck!

Comment: So you want text2.txt to contain `name=Peter surname=Peterson email=peterpeterson@gy.com`?

Comment: exactly. it would help to have a loop but I guess I can figure that one out once I understand how to get the data from the other file

Comment: Does the name always consist of exactly two words?

Comment: The `line1:` and the double quotes `"` included in the `file1` ?

Comment: I have edited my original post to make things more clear

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one using `awk`:

```sh
awk -F '[.@ ]' '{print "name="$1"\n" "surname="$2"\n" "email="$1"."$2"@"$3"."$4"\n" "password="$5}' textfile1 > textfile2
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. it creates variables for every single user. I want one variable. And depending on the line im currently reading, it should adjust its value.

Comment: @SenorPantalones Can you please share expected output?  Please add expected content of file2.txt in the main post

Answer (score 0):

Remember part of strings and construct what you need.

```
sed -r 's/([^.]*).([^@]*)@([^ ]*).*/name=\1 surname=\2 email=\1.\2@\3/' text1.txt > text2.txt
```